# Combining transfer and size effects, or combining translation and resizing

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to invoke a command that will cause an html element and its children (call that target) to move to another html element (call that destination). As the target moves, I want it to re-size to fit the destination.

You can visualize this as the jQuery UI transfer effect, but instead of transferring an outline, it transfers the entire element.

I figure I could write code to asynchronously translate and perform a resize effect, but I'd prefer a less laborious process. Is there a plugin or some other canned functionality I can exploit to do this? Or would CSS3 + HTML5 allow me to easily accomplish this?

I have two columns, 'sub' and 'main'. When I click on an element in sub, I want it to transfer to main with the desired effect. The two columns are sortable, accomplished with the JQuery UI sortable plugin.

Here's a sample of my HTML and the relevant CSS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $(".column").sortable(
                    {
                        handle: '.widget-title',
                        revert: true,
                        scroll: true,
                        placeholder: 'hover',
                        cursor: 'move',
                        revert: true,
                        connectWith: ".column",
                        opacity:0.5
                    }
                );
$( '.segment' ).addClass( 'ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all' )
                    .find('.widget-title')
                        .addClass('ui-widget-header ui-corner-all');
            }); 
        </script>
```

```
        <div id="sub" class="column">
            <div class="segment">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="widget-title">
                            <h4>Widget 1</h4>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="transfer-to-main btn">
                            <p>To Main</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="widget-content">                            
                            <p>When Colonel Arcadio Buendia stood before the firing squad he 
                            thought of the day his father took him to see ice.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>              

            <div class="segment">
                <div class="widget-title">
                    <h4>Widget 3</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="transfer-to-main btn">
                    <p>To Main</p>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-content empty-widget">                                           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body, #dashboard {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

div.column {
  float: left;    
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: thin;
}

div.empty-widget {
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}

#main{
    width: 50%; 
    height: 100%;
}

.btn{
    background-color: blue;
}

.ui-effects-transfer { border: 2px dotted gray; background-color: red; }

#sub {
    width: 30%
}

div.segment {
    margin: 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
}

.widget-title {
    margin: .3em;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: .2em; 
}

.ui-sortable-placeholder {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    visibility: visible !important;
    height: 50px !important
}

.ui-sortable-placeholder * {visibility: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the code in [**This Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexBay/ZaUgW/20/) good for your work?

Only 2 lines (could be one) of JavaScript code, with `animate()` and without [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I didn't give enough information in my question. I'll edit it in.

Comment: When I use that code, the element stays in place and re-sizes. Could it be because I'm using relative sizes and the jQuery UI sortable plugin?

Comment: You need the elements to be positioned absolutely in order to move them

Comment: For any and all methods of movement?

Comment: If you cannot show the code, I can't help you much more. Look at the new edited Demo now

Comment: I should have posted that to begin with. I'll edit it in now.